# Magento 1.9.1.0 and PHP 7 (RC6) - Customer login

Tags: magento-1.9

We have setup Magento shop on PHP7, everything works fine, except customer login and registration. After debug on registration page the problem is in observer class Mage_Persistent_Model_Observer_Session in method synchronizePersistentOnLogin. Does anyone can help with this?

Comment: What is the problem you're having?